# SVG is working on plain HTML file but loses alignment when integrated in Angular

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created an svg circular progress bar.

But when I am putting the same svg in my angular component html it is losing its alignment. [image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 35.83098862 35.83098862" width="60" height="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="circle-chart__background" stroke="#d3d7dd" stroke-width="4" fill="none" cx="17.91549431" cy="17.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
    <circle class="circle-chart__circle" style="transform:rotate(-90deg);transform-origin: center;" stroke="#222" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="80,100" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" cx="17.91549431" cy="17.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
    <text class="circle-chart__text" data-name="20%" transform="translate(9 20)" font-size="7.5" font-family="Graphik-Semibold, Graphik" font-weight="600" style="mix-blend-mode: normal;isolation: isolate"><tspan x="0" y="0">80%</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

I have added the snippet in the sandbox. Here is the link - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-johnson-yo19y?file=/src/app/app.component.css

Same snippet works fine in html.

Comment: Likely some CSS in your page is moving stuff

Comment: @mplungjan I have not added any css. I have not added any code in the component scss also. :(

Comment: There is nothing obvious from what you have posted. But the problem is obviously related to the component.  You should create a [mcve] of a page with your component so we can see for ourselves the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have added the code snippet sandbox link. I am only using this svg nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the `viewbox` attribute is wrong. It should be `viewBox`.

Comment: You are a life saver. I spent so much time trying to understand the issue, Thank you so much.